# Overclocking monitor refresh rate decreases overall quality [HDMI]

Tags: windows-10, hdmi, 1080p

So im trying to bumb my monitors refresh rate a bit and i find out i can go from **60** to **80hz**. But when i switch to 80hz i find that the color scheme is turned on its head. **Grey** becomes **light black**, **blue** turns to **purple**. I even lowered it down to **61 hz** and still i got bad quality. *(What im thinking is that my HDMI cable can't handle **1080p** AND over **60hz**.)*

Is there any way of **increasing** my monitor **refresh rate** without **loosing** quality?

Comment: I mean you've kind of answered your own question here... the monitor can handle it fine, but maybe the cable cannot.

Comment: standards: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data#EDID_Extensions_assigned_by_VESA  In that page go down to Limitations .. you're probably hitting them.  Also here in straight HDMI version comparisons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison 60hz, when you go outside that, you're dependent on EDID working.

Comment: @7h3w1z4rd ... wikipedia.. Extended Display Identification Data (EDID) is a data structure provided by a digital display to describe its capabilities to a video source (e.g. graphics card or set-top box). It is what enables a modern personal computer to know what kinds of monitors are connected to it.... SO .. standard is 1080p 60hz HDMI you want to do 75 or 85hz .. your monitor has to support it and tell the video source "hey i support this, can you send it?" etc etc etc that's what EDID can get you.  It helps the card know what formats it can send (timing, refresh, etc)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have ran into a problem with the version of HDMI that your currently using. What I would suggest is to look at the back of the monitor to see if there are any other plugs that you can use to connect to the computer.

Display port would be the best option but failing that DVI might work. If you have those ports and it still doesn't work then you might want to look at getting a graphics card (assuming your running the monitor of the built in GPU). You don't need a fancy one just something with the correct ports that can support the monitor(s) you want to run. Hope this helps :)

Comment: try getting a hold of a DVI cable just to confirm that it isn't a HDMI limitation issue